# How to show table from other controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got two controllers (`Users`, `Posts`) with two tables, but I need to pull all the posts from `Posts` table posted by `User.id` 
No matter what I did, I receive `NoMethodError` in `Users#show`

user_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index 
    @users = User.all 
    @posts = Post.all 
  end
  def show 
    @posts = Post.all 
  end
end
```

How do you people usually show table from other controller in another controller?

```
Full error:

NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing ~/users/show.html.haml where line #37 raised:
undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #37):

34
35 %p
36 %b TEST:
37 = @post.first

Rails.root: ~
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/users/show.html.haml:37:in `_app_views_users_show_html_haml___489713080_88351100'
```

Comment: give your code...that's throwing error.

Comment: For example, I'm trying to test this "= @Post.first". Seems that controller Users doesn't see Posts controller and it's table. No matter that I added "belongs_to :User" in my model Posts and "has_many :posts" in model Users. By the way, code is HAMLed

Comment: Can you add the full error trace?

Comment: You need to remember you're not pulling data from the other _controller_ - you're pulling from the other _model_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@post.first` this code raises the exception. You defined `@posts` not `@post`!

Answer (score 0):

if you want "all the posts from Posts table posted by `User.id`', replace `@posts = Post.all` for `@posts = @user.posts` on `#show` method